# Accessing fields of structs in array

Tags: perl

I have an array of structs (from Class::Struct) and I am having trouble accessing their 'fields'. I've looked at other solutions such as [Perl - Class::Struct Deferencing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370186/perl-classstruct-deferencing-array) and Perl documentation without success. My code is:

```
use Class::Struct;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

struct( Tag => {
    attributes => '%',
    value => '$'
});

my @data = [];
push @data, Tag->new(attributes => { 'id' => 1 }, value => "hello world!");
dump @data;



my $tag = $data[0];
my $value = $tag->value;
print $value, "\n";
```

I've tried variations on blessing $tag with 'Tag' (since can't call value on unblessed ... is the current error), dereferencing $tag as a hash, and more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is in initialization of `@data`:

```
my @data = []; # the same as my @data = ( [] );
```

You declare array called `@data` and initialize it with one empy array ref. 
Next you push second element to array using `push`. Your class now in `$data[1]`.
So fixed example:

```
struct( Tag => {
    attributes => '%',
    value => '$'
});

my @data;
push @data, Tag->new(attributes => { 'id' => 1 }, value => "hello world!");

my $tag = $data[0];
my $value = $tag->value;
print $value, "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent a couple hours on that and never would have figured out the problem. Data dumper even showed [] in the array and I ignored it every time.